# SqlExceptionHelper - FATAL: password authentication failed for user - Spring Data JPA - Vault - Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hashicorp-vault

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data JPA connecting to a Postgres Database using Spring Cloud Vault Database. And, the application keeps loosing connection to the database periodically. Only solution is to restart the application.

Here's the configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: application-name-api
  cloud.vault:
    kv-version: 2
    host: vaulthost.net
    port: 8200
    scheme: https
    authentication: TOKEN
    token: XXX_VAULT_TOKEN_XXX
    database:
      role: database_write_role
    kv:
      enabled: false
    database:
      enabled: true
      backend: database
      username-property: spring.datasource.username
      password-property: spring.datasource.password
  config:
      import: "vault://"
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://db-postgresql:11111/defaultdb?sslmode=require"
    testOnBorrow: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 2
      connection-timeout: 3000
      idle-timeout: 10000
      minimum-idle: 1
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  profiles:
    active: dev
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 5MB
      max-request-size: 5MB
```

When the application is deployed to a Linux Box it works well, and is able to connect to the database. However, after a day the connection errors out with the following exception:

```
2023-08-26 17:58:42,875 WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8600-exec-8] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
2023-08-26 17:58:42,876 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8600-exec-8] HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.
2023-08-26 17:58:42,877 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8600-exec-8] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "v-token-xxxxxxx-fffffffxxxxxxxxzzzzzz-1692899441"
2023-08-26 17:58:42,878 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api].[dispatcherServlet] [http-nio-8600-exec-8] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "v-token-xxxxxxx-fffffffxxxxxxxxzzzzzz-1692899441"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:646)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here are the entries in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.toratoratora</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>application-api</name>
    <description>Application API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
        <validator.version>1.7</validator.version>
        <hibernate-types-52.version>2.14.0</hibernate-types-52.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-collections4.version>4.4</commons-collections4.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.11.0</commons-io.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.7.4</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <okhttp.version>4.10.0</okhttp.version>
        <jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>2.14.2</jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>
        <cactoos.version>0.55.0</cactoos.version>
        <commons-text.version>1.10.0</commons-text.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config-databases</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-types-52.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype-jsr310.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cactoos</groupId>
            <artifactId>cactoos</artifactId>
            <version>${cactoos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.spring.javaformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-javaformat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.31</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I understand that password is not working anymore. So spring cloud vault should refresh the password first.

```yaml
spring.cloud.vault:
    config.lifecycle:
        enabled: true
        min-renewal: 10s
        expiry-threshold: 1m
        lease-endpoints: Legacy
```

then code needs to refresh the datasource whenever password expires. Below is example code to do that

```java
@Configuration
public class VaultConfiguration {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private SecretLeaseContainer leaseContainer;

    @Autowired
    private HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.vault.database.role}")
    private String databaseRole;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        String path = "database/creds/" + databaseRole;
        leaseContainer.addLeaseListener ( event -> {
            if (!path.equals(event.getSource().getPath())) {
                return;
            }

            logger.info("Lease event {}, lease Id {}:", event, event.getLease().getLeaseId());

            if (event instanceof SecretLeaseExpiredEvent && RENEW == event.getSource().getMode()) {
                logger.info("Replace RENEW for expired credential with ROTATE");
                leaseContainer.requestRotatingSecret(path);
            }

            if (event instanceof SecretLeaseCreatedEvent && ROTATE == event.getSource().getMode()) {
                Map<String, Object> secrets = ((SecretLeaseCreatedEvent) event).getSecrets();
                String username = (String) secrets.get("username");
                String password = (String) secrets.get("password");
                logger.info("XXXXX New username = {}", username);
                hikariDataSource.getHikariConfigMXBean().setUsername(username);
                hikariDataSource.getHikariConfigMXBean().setPassword(password);
                logger.info("Soft evicting db connections...");
                hikariDataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().softEvictConnections();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also I suggest to use "min-renewal: 10s" or 60s

References:

- https://github.com/visa2learn/spring-cloud-vault-db-cred-rotation
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/advanced-topics.html#vault-lease-renewal